# Can a Windows 7 OEM disk be used to upgrade (no clean install) from XP

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, upgrade

I'm currently running Windows XP Pro on my PC. I'm looking at upgrading (no clean install) to windows 7. So I was looking at buying a OEM version online.

Is it possible to upgrade with an OEM disk OR do I absolutly need an upgrade version?

I've never actualy did an  upgrade before... Always did a clean install.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is no upgrade path from Windows XP to Windows 7.  Furthermore since you are not an OEM you shouldn't be buying OEM license.

Comment: @Ramhound: In some countries there is legally no difference between an OEM and a regular license. Everybody can by OEM licenses there even if Microsoft dislikes it...

Comment: Note that you probably want to install the 64 bit version of windows 7. (Unless you run less then 512MB RAM). And as far as I know there is no upgrade path for windows from 32 bit installations to 64 bit installations.

Comment: @Hennes there isn't because Windows XP 64 bit does not have an upgrade path to Vista 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to upgrade from from XP to 7 is to first upgrade from XP to Vista, then from Vista to Win7. This will keep users, programs, and all documents/settings

Additionally, you can use the Easy Transfer Wizard if you dont have/cant get a Win Vista installation disk. This WILL NOT keep your installed programs. You will need:

- A Windows 7 disk
- An external hard drive capable of holding all of your files (presumably several hundred gigabytes to be safe)
- Your PC

Insert the Windows 7 disk and go to `[CDDRIVE:]\support\migwiz` and run `migsetup.exe`. Select the option for backing up your things to an external hard drive, and then select what you want to backup.

Then, install Windows 7 cleanly as normal. Once into Windows, click start and in search, search for Easy Transfer and run the wizard again to IMPORT your old things.

As a reminder, you will have to reinstall all your programs with this method.

Comment: That sucks... It's a bummer that you need a "Vista Bridge" to do this process. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if the Easy Transfer Wizard comes in the OEM version?

Comment: Should be standard in every version, if I remember correctly. Possibly not standard. But long story short, for OEM, yes.